# Bulk update: increment field in MongoDB by a value from the query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to perform a MongoDB increment update, for example, `playerStats.update({}, {$inc : {stamina : $staminaRegen }}, {multi : true})` where `$staminaRegen` comes from the collection I'm performing the update on. For example, an entry in the collection would look like `{_id : playerId, stamina : 10, staminaRegen : 4}`. It's important that the staminaRegen is defined per player. Is there a preferred way to do this kind of operation in MongoDB? Of course, I could accomplish this by doing a separate query and update, but I would prefer to use only a single operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update expressions can't (currently) use reference fields to compute expressions, see this [outstanding ticket.](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345) You'll need to iterate through the documents and update each document using a function